# UINavigationController hiding navbar with custom transition delegate in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationViewController with two view controllers. The root view controller needs the navigation bar to be hidden, while in the second view controller, the navbar is visible.

I implemented custom transitions with UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

When I push the second view, everything is fine. However, when I pop the view and return to root, there's a jump in the root controller frame. It animates in as though it has a navigation bar and when the animation completes, the frame is re-adjusted to full-screen.

What's the proper way to do this? The default transitions don't display this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways to fix it:

1. Hide the navigation bar entirely from the navigation controller and add a custom navigation bar to the first screen, independent on the navigation controller.
2. Let only the first screen to be in a navigation controller and create a custom transition to the second screen, not using navigation controller's push but implementing the push animation by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I was starting to think of those options. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a way to do it without them.